# Attach to Like!andTweed function in cocos2d-x Android App

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, cocos2d-x

I created Android App that is made by cocos2d-x.
I'd like to implement  cooperation function with social network service (facebook and twitter )
For example, Like! button which separate news feed.tweet function.
But This function turned out to be a can of worms which I couldn't finish.

I found EziSocial. but I can't find any hints.
would you give me a
description of how to use and method of attach to existing app

Answer (score 0):

We have series of tutorials available on our website. http://ezibyte.com/tutorials/

Disclaimer: I am the creator of EziSocial Plugin